# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR' in running sql dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i made this sql dynamic string but when run this error shows "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'."

```
declare @cols as  nvarchar(max)
       ,@query as nvarchar(max);
set @cols = stuff(
                   (select distinct ','+quotename(MatName) from viewProjVsMat
                    FOR xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                 ,1,1,'');

set @query = 'select ProjName
                    ,'+@cols+'
            from viewProjVsMat
            pivot (Monut for MatName in ('+@cols+')
                  ) p';


execute(@query)
```

Comment: `Monut` needs to be included in an aggregate function such as sum, max, avg etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the line

```
pivot (Monut for MatName in ('+@cols+')
```

Here, `Monut` needs to be included in an aggregate function such as sum, max, avg etc.

For example:

```
pivot (SUM(Monut) for MatName in ('+@cols+')
```

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) for more on PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate functions depend on your requirement like AVG ,Min,Max

```
  pivot (
                AVG(Monut) for MatName in ('+@cols+')
                      ) p';
```

Your modified code

```
 declare @cols as  nvarchar(max)
           ,@query as nvarchar(max);
    set @cols =
     stuff(
                       (select distinct ','+quotename(MatName) from viewProjVsMat
                        FOR xml path(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                     ,1,1,'');

    set @query = 'select ProjName
                        ,'+@cols+'
                from viewProjVsMat
                pivot (
                AVG(Monut) for MatName in ('+@cols+')
                      ) p';


    execute(@query)
    Print @query
```